# Filling Borders after undistort results in unwanted artefacts

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using the OpenCV Function "undistort" to have a kind of barrel distortion. Of course I have now black borders and I wish to fill the black borders with the value `65535`which is required for my following processing pipeline. To achieve this behavior, I am executing the following code:

```
cv::undistort(src,dst,K,dis);
dst.setTo(65535,dst == 0);
```

where src is the original image, dst the image with the barrel distortion, K the camera matrix, and dis the distortion coeffizients. The function setTo will set all parameters that are 0 to `65535` to `0`.

This results in teh following exemplary image:

[image]

It can be seen that it is almost everywhere white, - the black large bar is wanted. However, there is still an outline around the image left. 
These are values which were not caught by the `setTo`-Function since they are not 0. On further inspection, they are showing a kind of linear tendency.

So my question is, if it is possible to "forbid" OpenCV to make these smooth edges when using undistort? Or is there any kind of solution to get rid of these values without destroying the ground truth? The shown image is only exemplary, the values that are outside on the edges may occur in the wanted ground truth

Comment: The easiest solution would be to expand your input image before you undistort, filling in with an appropriate background value.

Comment: is it possible to calculate the desired size so that the image afterwards may look exactly the same? (like 1.2 the size of the original image will give you the same image again with this distortion matrix) ?